# Obtener permisos para user_birthday y gender desde la API de Facebook

Tags: firebase, facebook, permisos, autenticación

Tengo una app hecha con vue y firebase, el cual tiene un login, para el login uso el servicio de auth de firebase. Sin embargo necesito obtener ciertos datos del usuario pero parece que por defecto no vienen incluido por defecto.
Firebase auth tiene un método para añadir al scope de la app esos datos, sin embargo no funciona.

Al parecer hay que pedir a Facebook cierta autorización, el caso es que estoy viendo la documentación pero estoy perdido, no sé por donde empezar.

Entonces en resumen que debo hacer para que mi app tenga permisos para acceder a ciertos datos del usuario?